# how to combine numbers from different ranges into one variable

Tags: javascript

how to combine numbers from different ranges into one variable

I have 3 ranges from which I recognize the value and set them to a variable, and then I try to add the values of these variables into functions. Why it doesn't work

```
<form action="range">
        <label>Рассчитай свои <br> накопления и доход</label>
        <div class="first__range">
                <div class="name">
                    <label>Сумма вклада</label>
                </div>
            <input id="rangeOne" type="range" min="0" max="1000000" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="two__range">
                <div class="name">
                    <label>Срок инвестирования</label>
                </div>
            <input id="rangeTwo" type="range" min="0" max="24" value="0">
        </div>
        <div class="three__range">
                <div class="name">
                    <label>Пополнение вклада</label>
                </div>
            <input id="rangeThree" type="range" min="0" max="30000" value="0">
        </div>
        </form>

        <div class="final_count">
            Сюда
        </div>
```

```
const rangeOne = document.querySelector('#rangeOne');
const rangeTwo = document.querySelector('#rangeTwo');
const rangeThree = document.querySelector('#rangeThree');

const finalCount = document.querySelector('.final_count')

rangeOne.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let a = rangeOne.value
});

rangeTwo.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let b = rangeTwo.value
});

rangeThree.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let c = rangeThree.value
});

function score() {
    let final = a + b + c;
    console.log(final)
}


score()
```

Comment: the variables `a`, `b` and `c` exist only within the scope they were defined (the callback functions of the event listeners)

Comment: You'll want to call `score()` not just once, but on every input event as well (or at least when submitting the form)

Answer (score 2):

a, b, and c are local in scope to each of your functions.  Declare a,b and c outside of your functions to make them global and then it will work.  Also, score() will run before you get the input values so you will need to change that, you could place score on a button or place it inside rangeThree

Answer (score 0):

As DCR said, you'll have to declare the variables a, b and c out of the functions.
Here's the working code:

```js
const rangeOne = document.querySelector('#rangeOne');
const rangeTwo = document.querySelector('#rangeTwo');
const rangeThree = document.querySelector('#rangeThree');

const finalCount = document.querySelector('.final_count');

let a = 0;
let b = 0;
let c = 0;

rangeOne.addEventListener('input', () => {
  a = parseInt(rangeOne.value);
  score();
});

rangeTwo.addEventListener('input', () => {
  b = parseInt(rangeTwo.value);
  score();
});

rangeThree.addEventListener('input', () => {
  c = parseInt(rangeThree.value);
  score();
});

function score() {
  let final = a + b + c;
  console.log(final)
}


score()
```

```html
<form action="range">
  <label>Рассчитай свои <br> накопления и доход</label>
  <div class="first__range">
    <div class="name">
      <label>Сумма вклада</label>
    </div>
    <input id="rangeOne" type="range" min="0" max="1000000" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="two__range">
    <div class="name">
      <label>Срок инвестирования</label>
    </div>
    <input id="rangeTwo" type="range" min="0" max="24" value="0">
  </div>
  <div class="three__range">
    <div class="name">
      <label>Пополнение вклада</label>
    </div>
    <input id="rangeThree" type="range" min="0" max="30000" value="0">
  </div>
</form>

<div class="final_count">
  Сюда
</div>
```